# "AllowIsolate" systemd option

Tags: linux, systemd, services

What is `AllowIsolate` systemD option found in some .service files ?

For example this is the contents of `/lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target` file in my system :

```
[Unit]
Description=Multi-User System
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
Requires=basic.target
Conflicts=rescue.service rescue.target
After=basic.target rescue.service rescue.target
AllowIsolate=yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AllowIsolate` allows a unit to be used in a manner similar to a runlevel. It is documented in [the `systemd.unit` manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#AllowIsolate=) (`man systemd.unit` on your system):

> `AllowIsolate=`
>
> Takes a boolean argument. If `true`, this unit may be used with the **systemctl isolate** command. Otherwise, this will be refused. It probably is a good idea to leave this disabled except for target units that shall be used similar to runlevels in SysV init systems, just as a precaution to avoid unusable system states. This option defaults to `false`.

`systemctl isolate` is documented in [the `systemctl` manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#isolate%20UNIT):

> **isolate *UNIT***
>
> Start the unit specified on the command line and its dependencies and stop all others, unless they have `IgnoreOnIsolate=yes` (see [systemd.unit(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#)). If a unit name with no extension is given, an extension of "`.target`" will be assumed.
>
> This is similar to changing the runlevel in a traditional init system. The **isolate** command will immediately stop processes that are not enabled in the new unit, possibly including the graphical environment or terminal you are currently using.
>
> Note that this is allowed only on units where `AllowIsolate=` is enabled. See [systemd.unit(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#) for details.